# Backing up images that are in iPhoto Library

Tags: backup

In my backup software, iPhotoLibrary is greyed out, so I can't select it to back it up.

How do I select the iPhotoLibrary to back it up?

(My back up program is Workspace Desktop (a Godaddy program).

Comment: From [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/1875): "Workspace Desktop is a suite of tools to help you manage email and Online Storage accounts." Is this actually software for manipulating your Mac, or does it only touch online services provided by GoDaddy? Please elaborate on how, exactly, you use this software, especially with screenshots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so even without your back-up program.
Inside the Pictures folder you'll see a file called **iPhoto Library**. Copy this file to a location you find suitable for your backup and vwoila, there is your back-up!

And just for the record, why don't you use TimeMachine?

Answer (score 0):

Most Simple Back Up

Drag the iPhoto Library from your Pictures Folder to another Disk. This will make a copy on that disk.

Slightly more complex:

Use an app that will do incremental back ups. This is a very good way to work. The first time you run the back up the app will make a complete copy of the Library. Thereafter it will update the back up with the changes you have made. That makes subsequent back ups much faster. Many of these apps also have scheduling capabilities: So set it up and it will do the back up automatically. Examples of such apps: Chronosync or DejaVu . But are many others. Search on MacUpdate